# Ошибка при переписывании Python-кода на C#

Tags: c#, python-3.x, sha1

Есть вот такая функция на Python:

```
def getToken(self, phoneNumber):
    keyDecoded = bytearray(base64.b64decode(self.__class__._KEY))
    sigDecoded = base64.b64decode(self.__class__._SIGNATURE)
    clsDecoded = base64.b64decode(self.__class__._MD5_CLASSES)
    data = sigDecoded + clsDecoded + phoneNumber.encode()

    opad = bytearray()
    ipad = bytearray()
    for i in range(0, 64):
        opad.append(0x5C ^ keyDecoded[i])
        ipad.append(0x36 ^ keyDecoded[i])
    hash = hashlib.sha1()
    subHash = hashlib.sha1()
    try:
        subHash.update(ipad + data)
        hash.update(opad + subHash.digest())
    except TypeError:
        subHash.update(bytes(ipad + data))
        hash.update(bytes(opad + subHash.digest()))
    result = base64.b64encode(hash.digest())
    return result
```

Перевел на вот такой код C#:

```
public string GetToken(string number)
    {
        byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(KEY);
        string signature = Convert.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String(SIGNATURE));
        string md5Classes = Convert.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String(MD5_CLASSES));

        string data = signature + md5Classes + number;

        List <byte> opad = new List<byte>();
        List<byte> ipad = new List<byte>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            opad.Add(Convert.ToByte(0x5C ^ key[i]));
            ipad.Add(Convert.ToByte(0x36 ^ key[i]));
        }

        SHA1 hash = SHA1.Create();

        byte[] btData = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data);
        ipad.AddRange(btData);
        byte[] temp = hash.ComputeHash(ipad.ToArray());
        opad.AddRange(temp);
        temp = hash.ComputeHash(opad.ToArray());

        return Convert.ToBase64String(temp);
    }
```

Но значения возвращаются разные. Подскажете где ошибка?

Comment: что делает _phoneNumber.encode()_ и почему в версии C# прибавляется просто `number`?

Comment: В Питоне функция `base64.b64decode` возвращает строку, используя при этом какую-то кодировку. На Шарпе функция `Convert.FromBase64String` возвращает массив байт - и для того чтобы получить строку надо знать ту кодировку, которую подразумевает функция из Питона. Вы "наугад" поставили `Convert.ToString` - и, видимо, ошиблись. То же самое можно сказать про другие места с преобразованием между последовательностью байтов и строкой.

Comment: Добавьте отладочный вывод *каждой* промежуточной переменной - и будет видно где ошибка.

Comment: вместо Convert.ToString пишите Encoding.UTF8.GetString